# token-box in one of the columns of jQgrid for multiple entries?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqGrid where for one of the columns I have to show Drop-down for items and allow *multiple* entries (considering Token-box). Currently the token box is appearing only for one row but I want it for all the records.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  createCSDGrid();
})

function createCSDGrid() {
    var lastsel
    $('#Grid').jqGrid({
        url: CSDDataUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],

        colModel: [

          {
            name: 'ID',
            index: 'ID',
            hidden: true,
            editable: true
          }, {
            name: 'a',
            index: 'a'
          }, {
            name: 'b',
            index: 'b'
          }, {
            name: 'c',
            index: 'c',
            editable: true,
            editoptions: {
              dataEvents: [{
                type: 'blur',
                fn: function(e) {
                  try {
                    $('#grid').jqGrid('editCell', 4, false);
                  } catch (e) {
                    //Do nothing}
                  }
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            name: 'd',
            index: 'd',
            editable: true,
            formatter: function(cellValue, options, cellObject) {
              var id = options.rowId;

              return "</p><input type='text' id='tokeninput-demo'/></p>";

            },
            editoptions: {
              dataEvents: [{
                type: 'blur',
                fn: function(e) {
                  try {
                    $('#grid').jqGrid('editCell', 5, false);
                  } catch (e) {
                    //Do nothing}
                  }
                }
              }],

            }
          }, {
            name: 'e',
            index: 'e',
            editable: true,
            editoptions: {
              dataEvents: [{
                type: 'blur',
                fn: function(e) {
                  try {
                    $('#grid').jqGrid('editCell', 6, false);
                  } catch (e) {
                    //Do nothing}
                  }
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        ],
        toolbarfilter: true,
        scrollrows: true,
        rowNum: 100,
        rownumbers: true,
        pager: '#jqGridPager',
        'cellEdit': true,
        'cellsubmit': 'clientArray',
        //editurl: addNewRowUrl,

        loadonce: true,
        recordtext: "Record Count: {1}",
        sortable: true,
        pgbuttons: false,
        pgtext: null,
        jsonReader: {
          repeatitems: false
        },
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumWidth: '50px',

        width: $('#Grid').width(),

        loadComplete: function() {
          $("#tokeninput-demo").tokenInput("http://jquery-tokeninput-demo.herokuapp.com", {
            theme: "facebook"
          });
        });

    }
```

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

there are two issues in your code:
1) In formatter, same id = "tokeninput-demo" is assigned to each column cell.

```
 formatter: function(cellValue, options, cellObject) {
                  var id = options.rowId;

                  return "</p><input type='text' id='tokeninput-demo'/></p>";

                },
```

2) in load complete you are accessing $("#tokeninput-demo") -> because all cell has same id, it is binding token input in first cell only.

```
 loadComplete: function() {
              $("#tokeninput-demo").tokenInput("http://jquery-tokeninput-demo.herokuapp.com", {
                theme: "facebook"
              });
            });
```

**Solution:**

1) Assign incremented id(unique id) to each cell in formatter
eg:

```
formatter: function(cellValue, options, cellObject) {
              var count = options.rowId;

              return "</p><input type='text' id='tokeninput-demo'+count/></p>";

            },
```

2) in load complete, use loop to access each cell and bind token
eg:

```
loadComplete: function() {

  for(int count=0; count<rowCount; count++)`enter code here`
    {
              $("#tokeninput-demo+'count'+").tokenInput("http://jquery-tokeninput-demo.herokuapp.com", {
                theme: "facebook"
              });
    }
            });
```